# As DCT Does Compaction of Energy, Can We Say IDCT Does Energy Spreading?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis

Like energy compaction transforms, the inverse transforms like IDCT are energy spreading transforms?

Comment: The logic is that if A is a DCT matrix and Ax=y, and y has more energy in compact form compared to x, then IDCT takes in y and outputs x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For certain kinds of signals (voiced speech, most music, etc.), the DCT is likely to compact, and thus the IDCT to (re)spread that more compact DCT result; but that is not true in general.  An impulse in either domain will be spread in the other domain, and vice versa, for that spread result, when inverse transformed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the question.
The concept is to think there are many bases to represent Vectors / Signals.

One of them is using the DCT base.
Now every base has its own advantages on different type of signals.
It happens to be that images are very sparse and energy compact in their DCT representation.
Hence it is used for "Compression" (JPEG).
Yet, not all signals will have this property with respect to the DCT base.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I agree with you and hotpaw2.  I wanted to confirm that whatever the signals DCT compacts, IDCT spreads the outputs of the DCT - as it gets back the original vector from the output of DCT.